# Absolute value of difference between entropies (of two distributions)

Tags: probability, inequality, information-theory, entropy

I have the following inequality for the $L_1$ distance between two distributions $Q$, $Q^n$ on a finite set $B$:

$$\|Q-Q^n|| < \frac{2|B|}{n}\leq \frac{C}{n} \leq \frac12 $$

Assuming $C\geq2|B|$, $n\geq|B|$ and
the $L_1$ distance is defined as $\|Q-Q^n\| =\sum_{b\in B}|Q(b)-Q^n(b)| $

Here, $Q^n$ is an empirical distribution on $B$ that is induced by a sequence $(x_i)$ of length $n$ where $x_i\in B$ $\forall i$. Now, I don't know how one can show the following using the above inequality:

$$|H(Q)-H(Q^n)|<\frac{2C\log(n)}{n}$$

where $H(Q)$ and $(H(Q^n))$ is the entropy w.r.t. $Q$ and $(Q^n)$.

I tried several ways, it did not work out. Does anyone have any idea, or is there some result (other than the inequality $H(Q)\leq \log_2(|B|)$) I could use here?

Thank you!

Comment: 1. Could you clarify what is $Q^n$? (If it's a empirical distribution, it would be random...)  2. Don't we need $n \ge 4 |B |$ to get the inequality? 3. Your $L_1$ definition lacks the absolute value.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, you were right, I forgot the absolute value in the $L_1$ definition. To be more precise about $Q^n$: It is an element of the set of types $\mathbb{T}_n(B)=\{\mu\in \Delta(B),\quad T_n(\mu)\neq\emptyset\}$, where $T_n(\mu)$ is an n-type set. W.r.t. your second comment I cannot say anything - what I have written down is given in the paper I am looking at at the moment. Thank you for your help, any additional comments are much appreciated!